# Outputting results from ksmirnov from Stata into Excel

Tags: stata

I have results from a `ksmirnov` test in Stata and want to output them, ideally using something from the `estout` suite. Any advice?

I've tried the following but it hasn't worked out well:
`ksmirnov GenericShare_noRepack, by(year)`
`gen _p=r(p)`
`estpost summ _p`

Comment: If you want just to export the P-value as a scalar, I suggest `putexcel` only.